single axis line in foreground
I have the following tex code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % set layers,
        xmin=-2.5, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-1.1, ymax=2.3,
        zmin=-2.1, zmax=3.0,
        view={65}{35},
        axis lines=center,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        ztick=\empty,
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel style={anchor=west},
        zlabel style={anchor=south},
        % every inner z axis line/.append style={/pgfplots/on layer=axis foreground},
        ]

        \addplot3 [
        domain y=0:2,
        domain=-2:2,
        surf,
        faceted color=pink,
        fill=pink,
        samples y=2,
        samples=2,
        ] {-y};

        \addplot3 [
        domain y=0:2,
        domain=-2:2,
        surf,
        faceted color=pink,
        fill=pink,
        samples y=2,
        samples=2,
        ] {y};

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

What I want is to only have the z-axis on top of the surfaces.
I tried to use the layer concept of pgfplots but I was not successful.
If anyone could give me a hint on how to use layers properly, I would be very grateful.

I don't know why layers don't work in your case, but a workaround would be to draw the z axis in a separate axis environement:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-2.5, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-1.1, ymax=2.3,
        zmin=-2.1, zmax=3.0,
        view={65}{35},
        axis lines=center,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        hide z axis,
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel style={anchor=west},
        ]

        \addplot3 [
        domain y=0:2,
        domain=-2:2,
        surf,
        faceted color=pink,
        fill=pink,
        samples y=2,
        samples=2,
        ] {-y};

        \addplot3 [
        domain y=0:2,
        domain=-2:2,
        surf,
        faceted color=pink,
        fill=pink,
        samples y=2,
        samples=2,
        ] {y};

      \end{axis}
      
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        xmin=-2.5, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-1.1, ymax=2.3,
        zmin=-2.1, zmax=3.0,
        view={65}{35},
        axis lines=center,
        hide x axis,
        hide y axis,
        ztick=\empty,
        zlabel style={anchor=south},
        ]

    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


